# BASH - crontab is always running except the python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

When i run this script from shell /var/tmp/server_always_alive.sh manually has no problem works. But when i let it run with crontab it never running even all the logics are correct.

How can i make the python server.py run via this crontab?

```
sun@sun-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ uname -a
Linux sun-Inspiron-One-2320 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/var/tmp/server_always_alive.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test 1"
echo "test 2"
# 58888 TCP port is server port of server.py, if its not running server.py has to execute auto
main=$(export DISPLAY=:0.0 && lsof -i tcp:58888 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')
if [ -z "$main" ]; then
        export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /var/tmp/python/server.py &
        sleep 2
        break
fi
echo "test 3"
echo "all runs except python server.py"
```

crontab :

```
* * * * * /var/tmp/server_always_alive.sh &
```

Comment: You should ask this question in the Super User site.

Comment: There's no need for the `&` in the `crontab` line. Your bash script should terminate normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference to alternative workout.

**Step 1:** Put python script on this following script= save it in `/var/tmp/main.sh`

A) NON GUI BASED

```
#!/bin/sh
script='/my/python/script/is/here/ok.py'
/usr/bin/python $script &
```

B) GUI (GTK/TK etc)

```
#!/bin/sh
script='/my/python/script/is/here/ok.py'
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/python $script &
```

**Step 2:** now make a file in `/etc/init.d/scriptname_what_ever_feed_i_name` with following (copy paste)

```
#! /bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DAEMON=/home/CHANGE _ ____ HERE ______ to the Step 1 file name
PIDFILE=/var/run/scriptname.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
     log_daemon_msg "Starting feedparser"
     start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  stop)
     log_daemon_msg "Stopping feedparser"
     killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     PID=`ps x |grep feed | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
     kill -9 $PID       
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  force-reload|restart)
     $0 stop
     $0 start
   ;;
  status)
     status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON atd && exit 0 || exit $?
   ;;
 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/atd {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
   exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

**Step 3:** make it executeable `chmod +x /etc/init.d/scriptname_what_ever_feed_i_name` and `chmod -R 777 /etc/init.d/scriptname_what_ever_feed_i_name` so that as any user you can execute it without sudo.

**Step 4:** for example:

`/etc/init.d/scriptname_what_ever_feed_i_name restart`

or

`* * * * * /etc/init.d/scriptname_what_ever_feed_i_name restart`

WORKING - and much better/safer.

```
ps aux | grep python
root      5026  0.5  0.3 170464 19336 pts/0    S    07:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/python/server.py
```

Now you can start and stop your python script using the command /etc/init.d/scriptname start or stop manually or cron etc

Answer (score 0):

`DISPLAY=:0.0` indicates your python 'server' is connecting to an X server. Why?

Cron won't have the necessary X "cookie". <strike>, and almost certainly won't be running as the same user as the X server.</strike>

**edit:** I'll take you at your word that you're running as the correct user.

**edit:** If you *really* need to run a graphical program from cron, try

```
xhost +si:localuser:`whoami`
```

Comment: That is not correct information: i can see crontab logs its running with correct usernames: `Jan  8 05:02:01 sun-Inspiron-One-2320 CRON[8589]: (sun) CMD (/var/tmp/server_always_alive.sh &)` without any errors and its not first time i am doing this, i used like this before and it always worked. is it a Kernel BUG or Python BUG?

Comment: Did you read what I said about `DISPLAY` ? You almost certainly can't run an an X client program from cron.

Comment: New rule of the internet. You don't get to call ANYTHING a "bug" until you know how to debug it *(that goes doubly for the Linux kernel :-)*

Comment: xhost +si:localuser:`whoami` when i used its saying: localuser:sun being added to access control list

Comment: Still from cron its not running the graphical program. i have applied `localuser:sun being added to access control list`

Comment: Ok, so that means the user `sun` is now allowed to connect to the X server from unix domain sockets on the local machine. If your program is an X client, it should now be able to connect (even from cron).

Comment: Do you have any errors in your `/home/sun/.xsession-errors` that relate to your program?

Comment: NO - it does not work even if i do * * * * * sun export DISPLAY=:0.0 && tothe.shfile & and i have no specific error in /home/sun/.xsession-errors related to GUI

Comment: What does `server.py` actually *do*?

Comment: CCTV - monitoring for security.

Comment: Ok, I accept that my question was vague. *How* does it do that. Does it really *need* to run as a graphical program? Does it have a 'headless' mode?

Comment: Just like daily computer.

Comment: What does that mean? You say `something` doesn't run. Then you don't specifically say what `something` actually does. Did you develop `server.py`? Can you get access to the developer?

Comment: I am going to change the kernel to 3.12 and check how crontab works now.

Comment: If it runs from the shell, it OBVIOUSLY (that it doesn't run from cron) has nothing to do with the linux kernel. You don't seem interested so much in *understanding* the problem; rather you seem interested in a 'machine gun' approach -- trying as many unlikely things as possible in the hope that something might stick.

Comment: I have my own laptop and other 10 systems, all running from crontab GUI without any issue. only this machine have this problem.

Comment: Congratulations -- so you can AB test! What's different about the `environment` when run from cron? (on 'good' machines, and on your 'bad' machine). That's a good place to start (it's almost always environment variables when dealing with cron issues).